# Filter newest questions by favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, filtering

Sometimes I want to view all the newest questions, but narrow down my search to tags marked by me as favorites. I don't want to limit my search to only one, selected tag and I am too lazy to type all the tags in my search window or click them one by one. Is multitag-filtering for favorite tags doable with simple mouse click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a simple *click**, but you can [search for `intags:mine is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion) and sort by newest.

<sub>*Well, unless you want the results on Stack Overflow and use the link in this post, but…technicalities</sub>

Comment: That will have to do, thank you :)